# dynamic looping in a template's attribute property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a template that repeats for as many items in a data object. However, according to Quasar, I need a v-slot property targetting the table row and I have numerated the rows to help me achieve this. Problem is, I need to read that v-slot dynamically. I'm having a hard time explaining this so just let me show you:

Quasar table syntax looks like this:

```html
<q-table :data="allLockbox" :columns="columns" row-key="name">
  <template v-slot:body-cell-1="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <p>
        This is row 1
      </p>
    </q-td>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:body-cell-2="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <p>
        This is row 2
      </p>
    </q-td>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:body-cell-3="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <p>
        This is row 3
      </p>
    </q-td>
  </template>
  ... ... ...
  <template v-slot:body-cell-nth="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <p>
        This is row nth
      </p>
    </q-td>
  </template>
</q-table>
```

The data has an array with as many rows as there may be, ex:

```
worktransfers: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
```

Ideally, I would like to run a v-for to loop through the array and produce 7 templates in this case. The VueJS documentation allows v-for in templates without a key (which also creates a bug inside the loop, but whatever for now). My problem is...How can I make the `v-slot cell name` dynamic so that it renders the cell name according to the loop index?...I've tried this:

```
<template v-for="(worktransfer, index) in worktransfers" v-slot:body-cell-{{index}}="props">
```

and also string literal

```
<template v-for="(worktransfer, index) in worktransfers" `v-slot:body-cell-${{index}}`="props">
```

Neither works. How do I make that cell name dynamic to data so that it loops the template as body-cell-1, body-cell-2, body-cell-3, etc...?

Comment: Try `v-slot:[\`body-cell-${index}\`]="props"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation re. dynamic slot names is here

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names

two requirements

- vue 2.6.0 +
- use `[]` brackets : `v-slot:[dynamicSlotName]`

As @Ricky pointed out in his comment, this should work

```html
  <template v-slot:['body-cell-'+index]="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
      <p>
        This is row {{index}}
      </p>
    </q-td>
  </template>
```

### update

here is a jsfiddle showing dynamic component naming working  https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/mLe4v8j7/

code:

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
  template: `<div class="parent">
        <h4>Parent Component</h4>
        
        <h3>computed</h3>
            <child>
          <template v-for="(item, i) in slotNamesDynamic" v-slot:[item]="props">
            <p>computed {{props.text}}</p>
          </template>
        </child>
        
        <h3>dynamic</h3>
            <child>
          <template v-for="(item, i) in slotNames" v-slot:['body-cell-'+item]="props">
            <p>dynamic {{props.text}}</p>
          </template>
        </child>
        
        <h3>function</h3>
            <child>
          <template v-for="(item, i) in slotNames" v-slot:[slotname(item)]="props">
            <p>function {{props.text}}</p>
          </template>
        </child>
        
      </div>
    `,
  props: ['slotNames'],
  computed: {
    slotNamesDynamic() {
      return (this.slotNames || []).map(n => 'body-cell-' + n)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    slotname(id) {
      return 'body-cell-' + id
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
      <div class="child">
        <h4>Child Component</h4>
        <slot name="body-cell-0" text="component slot 'body-cell-0'">1
        </slot>
        <slot name="body-cell-1" text="component slot 'body-cell-1'">2
        </slot>
        <slot name="body-cell-2" text="component slot 'body-cell-2'">3
        </slot>
      </div>`,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    slotNames: ["0", "1", "2"]
  }
})
```

```css
.child{
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent :slot-names="slotNames"></parent>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is odd lol my backticks are converting upon saving to `[&#x60;body-cell-${index}&#x60;]` .... a prettier issue in VSCode?

Comment: It didn't work. It broke compilation and nothing in the console telling what went wrong. I have bring it back to a stable point again before I try anything else

Comment: Another alternative is to create a method that returns the dynamic slot name string. `methods: { getRowSlotName(index) { return \`body-cell-${index}\` }`. Then: `v-slot:[getRowSlotName(index)]="props"`

Comment: I've tried it with 3 versions, in-place(dynamic), using computed, and using a function to pass a name. They all worked.  Please make sure your other syntax is correct and that you're using a recent version of vue

Comment: Sorry, it took a while to find the problem. I was passing an Object instead of an array and that caused some issues. I came back to this and used your dynamic example. Thank you. And thank you for the three different examples. I also foudn that quasar allows you to combine the templates into one and v-for the key to generate it all much easier. But your answer is still valid :)